# JFrame to Applet trouble

Tags: java, swing, applet, jframe, japplet

I have been trying to turn my Frames into applets, but I still cannot get them to run properly in BlueJ...I'm new to this still, could I please have some troubleshooting and help in my conversion efforts? Thanks in advance

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Option1 extends JApplet implements ActionListener {

private int click = 0;

public Option1() {
JFrame base = new JFrame ("Button Click Counter");
base.getContentPane().setLayout(null);
base.setSize(500,500);
base.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

JButton button = new JButton("Click Me!");
button.addActionListener(this);
JTextField count = new JTextField(click);
    this.add(button);
    this.add(count);
}
@Override
public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e) {
        click++; }

    }
```

and the other one

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.Random;

public class Option2 extends JApplet implements MouseListener {
double x;
double y;
public void init() {
addMouseListener(this);


JFrame base = new JFrame("Mouse Coordinates");
base.getContentPane().setLayout(null);
base.setSize(500,500);
base.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);


JTextField answer = new JTextField(x + "," + y);
}
@Override    
public void mouseClicked( MouseEvent e ) {
    x = e.getX();
    y = e.getY();

    this.setBackground(new Color((int)(Math.random() * 0x1000000)));
}
public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e){}
public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e){}
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e){}
public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e){}
}
```

also, if anyone could offer advice on how to a mouseclick to change the background to a random color (as attempted in Option2), that'd be great. Thanks!

Comment: See this tut, it might help you developing applets with swing. [Tut](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/developingApplet.html)